# Dialog box pop-up window splash screen

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a question which for someone will probably be the easiest question of the week but unfortunately for me, I am stuck.
I have a splash screen which i would like to have opened in a acDialog pop up box type format prior to the database opening in full screen mode.  At the moment the splash screen opens but in full screen mode as well.  Below is my code for when the splash screen opens and when it closes.  i just cant figure out how to reformat it.. Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmsplashscreen", acNormal, , , , acDialog
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSplashScreen"
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProjectPhaseMasterBoard", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Check your form settings for the splash screen. For now, lets use:
Popup = Yes; Modal = Yes; AutoCenter=Yes; AutoResize=No; FitToScreen=No; Also make sure you don't have vba code that does something like 'DoCmd.Maximize'

Comment: Ok..  i was missing the Popup selector..  But now, although i cut the form to my own measurements, there is excess lenght and a bit of excess width as well...  Thanks

Comment: I found it. .I had to select the resize to yes on the format screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup = Yes; Modal = Yes; AutoCenter=Yes; AutoResize=No; FitToScreen=No